# Downloading a file through PERL script

Tags: perl

I have the below PERL script that tries to download a file that contains the output of that script.

I face an error which says:

> Can't call method "header" on an undefined value at C:/Apache24/cgi-bin/trim.pl

However my output file gets written properly at the right destination. Please help me out with fixing the code and get the output file downloaded.

```
use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );
use File::Basename;

my $q            = new CGI;
my $upload_dir   = "C:/Apache24/htdocs/files" ;
my ($bytesread, $buffer);
my $numbytes     = 1024;
my $trim_out_dir = "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/vijay/Metagenomics/NGSQCToolkit_v2.3/CGI_Out";
my $out_file     = "$trim_out_dir/trimmed.fasta";
my $safe_filename_characters = "a-zA-Z0-9_.-";

$q->cgi_error and error( $q, "Error transferring file: " . $q->cgi_error );

my $file         = $q->param( "seq" )     || error( $q, "No file received." );
my $length       = $q->param( "len");
my $quality      = $q->param( "qual");

open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$file" ) or die "$!";

while ($bytesread = read($file, $buffer, $numbytes)) { 
    print UPLOADFILE $buffer; 
} 

close UPLOADFILE;
system("Reads.pl -i $upload_dir/$file -n $length -o $out_file");
open ( DOWNLOADFILE, "<$out_file" ) or die "$!";

print $cgi->header(
    -type       => 'application/octet-stream'
    -attachment => '$out_file');

close DOWNLOADFILE;
```

Answer (score 3):

This does not compile with `strict`, and since you are using `strict`, it does not seem likely that this is the code you executed. Your `$cgi` object is never defined, and therefore would stop the script at compile time. This line:

```
print $cgi->header(
```

should probably be

```
print $q->header(
```

You should also know that

```
-attachment => '$out_file');
```

will mean that the `attachment` param will not contain the value of the variable `$out_file`, it will contain the literal name of the variable. If you want it to contain the value of the variable, you need to either remove the quoting, or use double quotes.

More importantly, you should also know that your script is very unsafe. You are using values directly from the cgi object without verifying them. Both the `open` statement and the `system` statement could easily be manipulated to execute arbitrary commands on your system. For example:

```
$out_file = "foo; rm -rf /";
system("Reads.pl -i $upload_dir/$file -n $length -o $out_file");
```

You may wish to read the [documentation on security](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html), and perhaps use [taint mode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode) (`-T` switch).

Comment: I have tweaked my script as below. As I am new to PERL I am unaware of the document security concepts.

    open ( DOWNLOADFILE, "<$out_file" ) or die "$!";

    print $q->header(
            -type => 'application/octet-stream'
            -attachment => "$out_file");
 
    close DOWNLOADFILE;

This time the script runs successfully, but the out_file is not available for download. Please can you help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
print $cgi->header(
```

you probably mean

```
print $q->header(
```

Using `use strict` should have caught this error.